# PHP Warning: Undefined array key

Tags: php, arrays, key, undefined, warnings

I have a Opencart 3.0.3.8 php 8.0. How can I fix this error?

> PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "admin-key" in
> /home/websitename/storage/modification/admin/controller/common/login.php
> on line 92
>
> this is a line 92.
>
> if ($this->request->post['admin-key'] != $this->config->get('config_adminkey')) {

see below complete code.

```
<file path="admin/controller/common/login.php">
    <operation>
        <search ><![CDATA[
        public function index() {
        ]]></search>
        <add position="after"><![CDATA[
        $data['config_adminkey'] = $this->config->get('config_adminkey');
    ]]></add>
    </operation>
    <operation>
        <search ><![CDATA[
        protected function validate() {
        ]]></search>
        <add position="after"><![CDATA[     
         if ($this->request->post['admin-key'] != $this->config->get('config_adminkey')) {
            header("Status: 404 Not Found");
            require  'view/template/extension/module/404.html';
            exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

`isset()` Should fix your problem.

Change this line:

`if ($this->request->post['admin-key'] != $this->config->get('config_adminkey'))`

to this one

`if (isset($_POST['admin-key']) !== isset($_GET['config_adminkey']))`

Comment: after changing the line. extension stop working. looks like we also need to change another line as well.

Comment: You should use isset($this->request->post['admin-key']) @MuhammadMirza